# File upload to cloud from application without exposing creditals

Tags: c#, file-upload, cloud, storage

I have an image upload application (C# desktop) for end users and I want to switch to the cloud(storage)(the VPS is to expensive and unlimited hosting providers don't allow image hosting scripts). 
In order to do that I need to embed the login credentials inside my application (delivered to the end users) and maybe update them according to changes. So it's not a solution to me because of security reasons (cracking and upload things that aren't images).

One solution would be to host a PHP script so that my application uploads to that script (check if it's a image) and than to re-upload that image to the cloud storage. The problem is, I use the double bandwidth.

Is there any cloud hosting model that enables me that (without paying the double bandwidth or additional fees for running the PHP application or other thenology) or how to "hide" the creditals?

I have about 5000 uniqe visitors a day with about 70 users online in each moment (google analytics). I am offering a free service in a free app without adds so i have no earnings and i would really try to keep it like that with minimal hosting costs :(

Comment: Why cant  you check the file type from the application (in .net) before you upload? This will solve you 'Double Bandwidth' problem.

Comment: Still, the user can bypass this protection (wireshark etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out Google App Engine and Blobstore. It's relatively easy to use (sorry, no PHP support tho!) and is free up to a specified limit, so you can develop without having to spend.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview

How it works:

1. Your C# app GETs to a short Python script that simply returns a URL
   that contains a random key (that Google gives your Python script)
2. Your C# app POSTs to that URL using an appropriate mime type.
3. Your C# app will be redirected to a final URL once the upload
   completes. That URL will again be a Python script, which will
   then record the uploaded URL (and any metadata) to prevent it from becoming orphaned.

Another advantage of using Google App Engine is that they offer image transforms (crop, scale) that will be handled on their end -- allowing you to ask for thumbnails, for example, without having to download the full sized image first.

For step 3, you could record the URL (really just the blobstore entry ID) to your main application. The point is: you don't want to lose that random key because that's the only way of retrieving the image file.

Comment: I saw that option but do i pay for the app execution time "On-demand Frontend Instances" is that it ?

I have about 5000 uniqe visitors a day with about 50-100 users online in each moment (google analytics). I am offering a free service in a free app without adds and i would really try to keep it like that :(

Comment: You don't pay for anything unless you hit the limit. The limit you will most likely hit first will be the bandwidth one since you are doing minimal processing, just puts and gets.